# C++ referencing operator in declaration

Tags: c++, reference

I am a beginner in C++, and this must be a really basic question. I understand & stands for referencing operation. For example, a = &b assigns the address of b to a. However, what does & in a declaration such as the following mean?

```
className& operator=(const className&);
```

Do the following make sense and what is the difference between the last line and the following?

```
className* operator=(const className*);
```

From the answers below, it seems --- as I understand it --- that the following is valid too. Is it? If it is, how is it different from the version with "&"?

```
className operator=(const className);
```

---

After reading the following answers and some more outside, I realized part of my original confusion stems from mixing up [reference as in general computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29) and [reference type as in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29). Thank you all who answered my question. All the answers clarify my understanding to different degrees, even though I can only pick one as the accepted answer.

Comment: I updated my answer to address the second form of the assignment operator.

Comment: @RSahu: Thank you. I am digesting it. I have more questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Assignment Operator

Understanding is best gained by example:

```
class A {
  int x;
public:
  A(int value) : x(value) {}
  A& operator=(const A& from) {     // Edit: added missing '=' in 'operator='
    x = from.x;
    return *this;
  }
};

A m1(7);
A m2(9);
m2 = m1;   /// <--- calls the function above, replaces m2.x with 7
```

Here, we defined the assignment operator.  This special method is designed to provide assignment capability to objects.

The reason that it returns a reference to *this is so you can chain assignments without excessive memory copies:

```
A m3(11);
m3 = m1 = m2;   /// <--- now, m3.x and m1.x both set to m2.x
```

Expanded as follows:

```
  m3 = ( something ) 
where
  (something) is a reference to the object m1 
  by result of call to m1.operator=(m2) method
such that
  the returned reference is then passed into m3.operator(...)
```

Chaining lets you do this:

```
(m1=m2).function(); // calls m1.function after calling assignment operator
```

Libraries such as boost leverage this pattern (for a different type of chaining example, see the program options library in boost) and it can be useful when developing a domain specific 'language'.

If instead full objects were returned from operator=, the chained assignment would at a minimum involve multiple extra copies of the objects, wasting CPU cycles and memory. In many cases things would not work properly because of the copy.

Essentially, using a reference avoids a copy.

### Note

In reality, (simplified explanation) a reference is just a fancy syntax for a C pointer.
In the common case, you can then write code with A.x instead of A->x.

### Caution

Returning a pure reference from a method is often dangerous; newcomers can be tempted to return a reference to an object constructed locally inside the method on the stack, which depending on the object can lead to obscure bugs.

### Your pointer example

It depends on what you return from the body of the method, but regardless, the following would instead return a pointer to some instance of className:

```
className* operator=(const className*);
```

This will compile and it even seems to work (if you return this from the method), but this does violate the [Rule of Least Surprise](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch11s01.html), as it is likely anyone else attempting to use your code would not expect the assignment operator to return a pointer.

If you think about base types:

```
int x=1; int y=2; int z; z=y=x;
```

will never ever do anything other than return integers - so having operator= return the assigned to object is consistent)

It also doesn't let you do this:

```
(m1 = m2).something
```

It also allows you to pass NULL which is something assignment operators don't typically want to care about.

Instead of writing

```
blah& operator(const blah& x) { a = x.a ; return *this; }
```

You would need to write:

```
blah* operator(const blah* x) { 
  if (x) { a = x->a ; return this; }
  else { /*handle null pointer*/
}
```

Comment: How does className& differ from className* declaration?

Comment: Then how does declaration with & differ from without it, say, className operator=(const className); ?

Answer (score 4):

The token `&` has three distinct meanings in C++, two of which are inherited from C, and one of which is not.

1. It's the bitwise AND operator (unless overloaded).
2. It's the address operator, which acts on an lvalue to yield a pointer to it. (Unless overloaded.) This is what is happening in `a = &b`.
3. **It denotes a reference type**. `const className&` as a parameter is a `const` *reference* to an object of type `className`, so when the function is called, the argument will be passed by reference, but it won't be allowed to be modified by the function. The function you gave also returns a reference.

Comment: I just added a question comparing declaration with * vs. &. Does your point 3. imply the only difference is the form allows modification whereas the latter does not?

Comment: @Hans pointers and references both enable modification, unless they are `const`. There are a few key differences. References are aliases to the original object, whereas pointers need to be dereferenced using `*`, or `->`, or something like that. References cannot be reseated to refer to a different object; pointers can be reassigned to point to a different object. References cannot be null. References are not real objects, and there can be no pointers to references, references to references, or arrays of references.

Comment: Then how does declaration with & differ from without it, say, "className operator=(const className);" if it is legitimate?

Comment: @Hans Passing by value makes a copy, whereas passing by const reference doesn't. Also, when you pass by value the function can change its copy (and the changes don't propagate back to the original object) but when you pass by const reference the function doesn't even have a copy to change.

Comment: If I drop "const", what you said about copy was still valid right?

Comment: @Hans yes, passing by reference, in general, does not create a copy. In this sense it is similar to passing by pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It means the function takes a reference to a `const className` and returns a reference to a `className`

Say you have a class like below:

```
class className
{
   public:
      className& operator=(const className& rhs)
      {
         this->a_ = rhs.a_;
         this->b_ = rhs.b_;
         return *this;
      }

   private:
      std::string a_;
      std::string b_;
};
```

You can use the assignment operator of the class as below:

```
className a;
className b;
className c;

c = b = a;
```

The above line is executed as:

```
c.operator=(b.operator=(a));
```

Now take another class that has the `operator=` defined using the second form:

```
class className2
{
   public:
      className2* operator=(const className2* rhs)
      {
         this->a_ = rhs->a_;
         this->b_ = rhs->b_;
         return this;
      }

   private:
      std::string a_;
      std::string b_;
};
```

You can use the assignment operator of the class as below:

```
className2 obj1;
className2 obj2;
className2 obj3;

obj2 = &obj1;
obj3 = &obj2;
```

The above lines are executed as:

```
obj2.operator=(&obj1);
obj3.operator=(&obj2);
```

However, such coding is not intuitive. You don't assign a pointer to an object. It is more intuitive to say:

```
className obj1;
className* objPtr = NULL;

objPtr = &obj1;
```

Comment: I am still trying to understand it. I added a third case in the original question. Could you please take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @Hans, the third form is almost like the first form. Only it can be more expensive depending on the nature of the object. It makes a temporary copy for the input argument when the `operato=()` function gets called. It also makes a temporary copy when the function returns. That's two additional copies per function call.

Comment: I am confused. In your first code, the "operator" in "className& operator=..." is presumably a reference to "*this". But is it, a reference, not a pointer to the address of "*this", which is then just "this" a pointer pointing to the address of "*this"? If so, why can you not simply return "this" just like in your className2 code?

Comment: When you use `int b = 10; int& a = b;`, then `a` is a reference to `b`. `a` can be changed to be reference to another variable.

When you use `int b = 10; int* a = &b;`, then `a` is a pointer that points to `b`. `a` can be changed to point to another variable.

In the first form, you have to use `return *this;` because you want to return a reference to the object that `this` points to.

Comment: Do you actually mean to say "When you use int b = 10; int& a = b;, then a is a reference to b. a can NOT be changed to be reference to another variable." as opposed to "a CAN be changed to ... another variable"?

Comment: @Hans, yes. That's what it means.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = &b
```

Here, `&` gives address of b.

```
className& operator=(const className&);
```

Here, `operator =` will take const reference of variable of type className.

You can say in C++, & is polymorphic.

Comment: You could also say that symbols in declarations have different meanings to symbols in expressions.